# CompileClassResult Invalid Type

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I'm developing some logic to compile all my classes and triggers in my org automatically every day. I found the following documentation to do it but when I tried running a simple command in the Execute Anonymous Window, I got the error below. Does anyone know why I'm having this error and how to get this working?

- [Production](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest.htm)
- Sandbox [Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_compileclasses.htm) [Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_compiletriggers.htm)
- [ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm) Class

  ```
  // Fails on this line with the error image below
  List<CompileClassResult> r = new List<CompileClassResult>();

  // Get a single Class to test with
  ApexClass tempClass = ([SELECT Body FROM ApexClass LIMIT 1]);

  // Example code from the Sandbox Class documentation
  try {
      r = apexBinding.compileClasses(new String[]{tempClass.Body});
  } catch (RemoteException e) {
      System.out.println('An unexpected error occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
  }

  // Show Results
  for(CompileClassResult tempResult : r)
  {
      if (!tempResult.isSuccess()) {
          System.out.println('Couldnt compile class p1 because: ' + tempResult.getProblem());
      }   
  }
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods and objects are part of SOAP  API and are not available from native apex.
Hence you are seeing the error.
You can move your logic to Java application as illustrated in the example in the documentation.
The snippet you have pasted is Java code.:)

For more info on  Getting started with SOAP  API
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm

Comment: When answering, avoid external links as there is no guarantee that those links will stay live for good. In addition to this, your answer is an advice more than a solution. Consider posting a working code instead.

Comment: @booky99 No problem.It is certainly confusing to have soap objects interspersed in apex documentation.Please vote as answer if it resolves your question.